# Integration of modified bessel function $\int_{x_1-\sigma}^{x_1+\sigma}x\exp(-t_1x^2)\cdot I_0(t_2x)\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

In fact I was originally trying to evaluate the following integral
\begin{align}
\int_{x_1-\sigma}^{x_1+\sigma}\int_0^{2\pi}x\exp\left(-c\left(x\sin\phi-a\right)^2-c\left(x\cos\phi-b\right)^2\right)\ d\phi\ dx\,,
\end{align}
where $c>0$, $a$, $b$ are some constants; and $x_1>0,x_2>0$.

I was able to simplify the above integration into the following form
\begin{align}
\int_{x_1-\sigma}^{x_1+\sigma}x\exp(-t_1x^2)\cdot I_0(t_2x)\ dx\,,
\end{align}
where $t_1>0$, $t_2>0$ are some constants, $I_0(t_2x)$ is the modified bessel function of the first kind. I wonder if there is a way to simplify this further.

Since right now I am use the following to approximate the above integration
\begin{align}
2\sigma\cdot x_1\exp(-t_1x_1^2)\cdot I_0(t_2x_1)
\end{align}
But it is still not accurate enough. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I just found that this can be computed using the Marcum Q-function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function